# Does calcification of the pineal gland negatively affect normal bodily functions?

Tags: biology, chemistry, fluoride

I received [this link](https://scottjeffrey.com/decalcify-your-pineal-gland/) from an associate of mine. It smells like pseudo-scientific bull to me, but there are a LOT of claims made in the article that I can't really debunk all by myself.

To quote from near the top of the online article:

> Studies show that pineal gland calcification:
>
> - Lowers productions of melatonin
> - Impairs the sleep-wake cycle
> - Disrupts the regulation of the circadian rhythm

Are these claims true? If so to what extent?

EDIT: Updated the title to better reflect what the question should have been in the first place. According to the comments below Fluoride can also affect calcification, so ideally answers would take Fluoride *and* Calcium build up into account.

Comment: I suggest you to make a step further and check some studies by [this search](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1280&bih=918&ei=KR_MXY67GsyNkgWRlbv4Aw&q=site%3Agov+fluoride+%22pineal+gland%22&oq=site%3Agov+fluoride+%22pineal+gland%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...3086318.3096638..3097474...0.4..0.116.2001.31j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i67j0.fMvr_VtSmmI&ved=0ahUKEwjO8_ezvuflAhXMhqQKHZHKDj8Q4dUDCAs&uact=5) . Then we can discuss if something remains unclear.

Comment: I think "calcify" is not the right word for your title, since we are not talking about calcium compounds at all.

Comment: @GEdgar https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5620462/ the pineal gland calcifies

Comment: And I expect that paper with "calcify" in the title is about calcium accumulating in he pineal, not flouride.

Comment: @GEdgar "...several pathological conditions might promote the premature pineal calcification. ... One of them is fluoride ... the high level of fluoride in the human pineal gland is positively related to its calcium accumulation of the gland [291]. Thus, decrease in environmental fluoride pollution may be helpful in delaying or avoiding premature pineal calcification." https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6017004/ So at least some scientists claim that fluoride causes calcification.

Comment: OK.  So that alleged duplicate is not a duplicate at all.

Comment: @GEdgar I agree, the question isn't a strict duplicate, but the answer of the question says "the fluoride concentrations being positively related to the calcium concentrations in the pineal gland".  I can vote to reopen if you think I should.

Comment: My fault for not being as explicit in the title too; After some more reading the question is more about the calcification of the Pineal gland negatively inhibiting normal bodily functions. Not whether flouride contributes to the calcification or not. I'll edit that.

Comment: @Scrambo I voted to reopen